# Const correctness with objects containing shared_ptr

Tags: c++, constants, shared-ptr

Consider the object:

```
class Obj
{
    public:
        Obj() : val(new int(1)) {}
        int& get() {return *val;}
        const int& get() const {return *val;}

    private:
        std::shared_ptr<int> val;
};
```

As expected, when the object is constructed and copies are made they can all modify the same value through the shared_ptr exposed by Obj.

```
    Obj nonconst1;
    Obj nonconst2(nonconst1);
    nonconst2.get() = 2;
    cout << nonconst1.get() << ", " << nonconst2.get() << endl;
```

It's also possible to copy-construct a `const Obj` object from one of the non const, which seems to do the correct thing in that it allows reading but not writing to the value - as expected the following code results in a compile error:

```
    const Obj const1(nonconst1);
    const1.get() = 3;
```

However it is possible to copy-construct a non-const Obj from the const one, which then does permit the value to be modified.

```
    Obj nonconst3(const1);
    nonconst3.get() = 3;
```

To me this doesn't feel const-correct.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour, whilst still allowing the copy constructor to work? In my real use case, I still want std containers of Obj to be possible.

Comment: Maybe, you should define the copy-constructor taking non-const reference so as to avoid making copy of `const` objects?

Comment: @Nawaz, that does work (I hadn't realised it was possible to use a non-const ref in a copy constructor). Unfortunately I'd also like const Obj to be able to copy construct other Const obj but attempting `Obj(const Obj& o) const` doesn't compile

Answer (score 2):

"To me this doesn't feel const-correct" yet it is: you're simply invoking a non const `get` method on a non const `Obj`. Nothing wrong with that.

If you really need the behaviour you're after, you could to use something like a const proxy to `Obj` but then your clients must be able to handle it of course:

```
class Obj
{
  //...
  //original class definition goes here
  //...
  friend class ConstObj;
};  

class ConstObj
{
  public:
    ConstObj( const Obj& v ) : val( v.val ) {}
    const int& get() const { return *val; }

   private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> val;
};

//usage:
class WorkingWithObj
{
public:
  WorkingWithObj();
  Obj DoSomethingYieldingNonConstObj();
  ConstObj DoSomethingYieldingConstObj();
};

WorkingWithObj w;
Obj nonconst( w.DoSomethingYieldingNonConstObj() );
nonconst.get() = 3;

ConstObj veryconst( nonconst );
veryconst.get() = 3; //compiler error

ConstObj alsoconst( w.DoSomethingYieldingConstObj() );
alsoconst.get() = 3; //compiler error
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit more? I don't see anything in `Obj` and the usage pattern?

Comment: @Nawaz added some comments / usage examples. Though I have to say I'd probably never use constructs like this in real code..

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't, unless you want to store a `shared_ptr<const int>`, in which case *nobody* can access it as non-const.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't break const correctness. The integer object pointed to by `val` is a distinct object, which isn't exclusively owned by the original object. Modifying its value doesn't affect the state of `Obj` objects.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to prevent this behaviour, whilst still allowing the copy constructor to work? In my real use case, I still want std containers of Obj to be possible.

You could specify a different copy constructor for copying from a `const` object - that means you can e.g. avoid copying the shared pointer and instead create the non-const object with a NULL pointer, or you could do a deep-copy of the pointed-to number.  I'd be pretty wary of doing this kind of thing though - it's weird to get different behaviours depending on the constness of the copied variable - I fear it'd make it very hard to reason about your program behaviour.  But, you must choose some behaviour or accept the current behaviour as `std::vector<>` will create copies sometimes - you can't simply leave it undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Manually implement a copy constructor of `Obj` which should then copy the shared pointer's content. This avoids modifying the content of `const1` via `nonconst3`, since they point to different int instances.

However, you want to avoid deep copies of *non-const* instances of `Obj` (where it's no problem and intended to reuse an old shared pointer). For this, you have to provide both const and non-const copy constructors and copy only in the const one:

```
class Obj
{
  public:
    //...
    Obj(Obj &o) : val(o.val) {}                            // not a deep copy
    Obj(const Obj &o) : val(std::make_shared(o.get())) {}  // deep copy
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't... But you can use `COW`, `deep-copy` pointer, when you can write to `value` (in non-const getter).

Or, you can write two `copy-ctors` (for `ref` do shallow copy, for `cref` do deep copy).

```
   A(A& obj) : pointer(obj.pointer) {}
   A(const A& obj) : pointer(new int(*obj.pointer)) {}
```